# I have an error in my Api regarding convert type decimal

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I am getting an error on this Line of code

```
result = Convert.ToDecimal(row[0]);
```

This is my API

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/boq/getlatestrate/{id}/{id}")]
public decimal GetLatestRate(DateTime wefDate, long ProductId)
{
        var result = 1;
        var dsBoq = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(AppDatabaseConnection, CommandType.StoredProcedure, 0, "GetLatestRate", new SqlParameter("@wefDate", wefDate), new SqlParameter("@ProductId", ProductId));

        if (dsBoq.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = dsBoq.Tables[0].Rows[0];               
            result = Convert.ToDecimal(row[0]);
        }

        return result;
}
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestRate]
    @wefDate DATE,
    @ProductId BIGINT
AS
    SELECT TOP 1 wefDate, RateDetails.Amount
    FROM Rate 
    INNER JOIN RateDetails ON Rate.Id = RateDetails.RateId
    WHERE wefDate <= @wefDate 
      AND RateDetails.ProductId = @ProductId
    ORDER BY wefDate DESC
```

This is result that comes after executing the stored procedure:

```
    execute GetLatestRate '2019-07-29', 4
```

```
wefDate         Amount
----------------------
2019-07-29      10.00
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Is that written code running?

Comment: No the code is not running. But i am bit confused that this code is written proper or not

Comment: I believe row[0] is returning the date as it is the first column in the result set. row[1] will return the Amount value.

Comment: I think var result = 1 will have implicitly typed it as an integer. Try var result = 1m (also I agree with JM_ you need row[1])

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think you should use "double" rather than "decimal". Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below. So even when the order of the column changes, you no need to modify your code.

```
result = Convert.ToDecimal(row[“Amount”]);
```

Also make sure Amount column doesn’t return null value.

```
select Top 1 wefDate, ISNULL(RateDetails.Amount,0) Amount
from Rate inner join RateDetails
```

Comment: Glad to help :)